# log4j2 loging database varchar2 error

Tags: java, oracle, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2 so as to loging databas. my code is below;

```
<JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="KRITIK_KISISEL_BILGI_LOG" bufferSize="1">
    <DataSource jndiName="jdbc/hope" />
    <Column name="ID" literal="SEQ_KRITIK_KISISEL_BILGI_LOG.nextval" />
    <Column name="KULLANICI_ID" pattern="%X{kkb_userid}" />
    <Column name="KULLANICI_IP" pattern="%X{kkb_userip}" />
    <Column name="ISLEM_TARIHI" literal="TRUNC(sysdate)" />
    <Column name="ISLEM_AKIS_YOLU" pattern="%m" />
    <Column name="ACIKLAMA" pattern="%X{kkb_kriter}" isClob="false"/>
    <Column name="VERSIYON" literal="0" />
    <Column name="TANITIM_ZAMANI" isEventTimestamp="true" />
    <Column name="TANITAN_KULLANICI_ID" pattern="%X{kkb_tanitanUserid}" />
    <Column name="LOG_TIPI_ID" pattern="%X{kkb_logTipi}" />
    <Column name="KULLANICI_KODU" pattern="%X{kkb_kullaniciKodu}" />
    <Column name="SUNUCU_ADI" pattern="%X{kkb_serverName}" />
</JDBC>
```

but when I pass more than 1000 character in to "ACIKLAMA" column I am getting ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column error. Hovewer, my "ACIKLAMA" column is varchar2(4000). So, why I can not insert 1000 to 4000 character into my "ACIKLAMA" column;

error code is :

```
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

thank you for you interest,

Comment: The error is not that your text is too long, but that you are trying to insert a value of type LONG in a column that is not of the same type. Could you post more log4j logging?

Comment: my database column is varchar2(4000) when I tried to pass more les than 1000 character to "ACIKLAMA" column it works but when the character number is increasing more than 1000 it gives error.

Comment: @EmreAltun See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01461_can_bind_a_long_value_only_for_insert_into_a_long_column.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error after inserting a `log4j2` entry into my database. 
I changed the data type of the column where more than 1000 chars have been inserted from `varchar2` to `CLOB`. Afterwards it worked.
Try to change the datatype of your `ACIKLAMA` column to `CLOB`.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for my problem; By adding this code to my log4j2.xml file, problem was solved.

```
isUnicode="false"
```